# Preview images before upload in MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

So I have been trying to find a good solution to previewing a local image before uploading it seeing as for security reasons you can't simply reference a local image in HTML...

```
<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xl-5">
<img src="@Model.ImagePath[outer]" class="img-responsive" id="@("ProductImage" + outer.ToString())" />
@if (Model.PreviewMode == false)
{
    <div style="position:absolute; bottom:60px">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImageFiles[outer], new { type = "file", onchange = ("PreviewImage('" + outer.ToString() + "')"), id = ("ProductImageUpload" + outer.ToString()) })
    </div>
 }
```

So this is a snippet of HTML from my project, as I am sure you guessed it comes out of a loop where `outer` was one of the controlling variables.

```
    <script>
    function PreviewImage() {
        // Where you will display your image
        var preview = document.querySelector('img');
        // The button where the user chooses the local image to display
        var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];

        // FileReader instance
        var reader = new FileReader();

        // When the image is loaded we will set it as source of
        // our img tag
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            preview.src = reader.result;
        }


        if (file) {
            // Load image as a base64 encoded URI
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        else {
            preview.src = "";
        }
    }

</script>
```

I got this code from another post and it works quite well for a single image, but for some reason as soon as I have multiple image and image inputs it stops working.

I would imagine somehow manually selecting the source and destination (by passing in an ID to the function)

Something like this:

```
var file = document.getElementById("ProductImageUpload" + ID).files[0];
```

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Any errors found in console log when using multiple image inputs, and how many file inputs used when the error starts tripping out?

Comment: Personally I have used Dropzone.js in my last project. Layout and appearance are customizable and there are code samples for using in conjunction with MVC .

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto No errors and no warnings, unfortunately

Comment: @derloopkat Really would like to see this method work for me but I will certainly look into that, thanks!

Comment: You're passing `outer` as a parameter to `PreviewImage` but the js function doesn't have it.

Comment: `function PreviewImage()` is a parameterless JS function, but your `onchange` event indicates a string parameter passed like this: `("PreviewImage('" + outer.ToString() + "')")`. Can you try adding function parameter like `PreviewImage(outer)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a great deal of research brushing up on my non-existent javascript skills and a consultation with higher powers, I have come up with this solution:

```
<script>
    function PreviewImage(ID) {

        // Where you will display your image
        //var preview = document.querySelector('img');
        var preview = document.getElementById("ProductImage" + ID);
        // The button where the user chooses the local image to display
        //var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
        var file = document.getElementById("ProductImageUpload" + ID).files[0];
        // FileReader instance
        var reader = new FileReader();

        // When the image is loaded we will set it as source of
        // our img tag
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            preview.src = reader.result;
        }


        if (file) {
            // Load image as a base64 encoded URI
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        else {
            preview.src = "";
        }
    }

</script>
```

Yes, yes the solution really was that simple.

But this works well no matter how many images you generate dynamically in your form. (see question HTML on how to invoke the method)